# TypeError: on_connect() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, mqtt

I try to execute this code on MQTT Broker(ubuntu server),

When get data from publisher will send to UDP_IP.

My code :

```
import json
import socket
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
# MQTT Settings
MQTT_Broker = "192.168.0.106"
MQTT_Topic = "#"
MQTT_Port = 1883
Keep_Alive_Interval = 45
UDP_IP = "192.168.0.108"
UDP_RAW_PORT = 5567
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def on_connect(mosq, obj, rc):
        mqttc.subscribe(MQTT_Topic, 0)

def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
        gps_handler(msg.topic, msg.payload)

def gps_handler(Topic, jsonData):
        jsonData = jsonData[1:-1]
        sock.sendto(jsonData, (UDP_IP, UDP_RAW_PORT))
        print jsonData

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
        pass

mqttc = mqtt.Client()

# Assign event callbacks
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

# Connect
mqttc.connect(MQTT_Broker, int(MQTT_Port), int(Keep_Alive_Interval))

# Continue the network loop
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

When I execute

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "port_5567.py", line 38, in <module>
    mqttc.loop_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1470, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 995, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1273, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1838, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2291, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_connack()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2349, in _handle_connack
    self.on_connect(self, self._userdata, flags_dict, result)
TypeError: on_connect() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I don't know why getting this error on ubuntu server,

On the Raspberry Pi(debian) it can work.

Comment: `mqttc.on_connect` is an instance method. It implicitly passes the instance as the first argument to the method (usually known as `self`)

Comment: Thanks! It's useful,but why doesn't need self on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: What version of python are you using on both machines (also what version of the python MQTT library)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though these functions are not originally defined as part of your class, when you call them as if they are methods of your class instance Python will pass the implicit `self` argument just as if they have been part of your class all along.

To fix, just add the `self` argument.

```
def on_connect(self, mosq, obj, rc):
        self.subscribe(MQTT_Topic, 0)

mqttc.on_connect = on_connect

# Repeat for other functions as well.
```

Comment: Thanks! It's useful,but why doesn't need self on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. This is the behavior of python in general.

Comment: No, you dont have to add a `self` argument ; you can see my answer for the correct signature.

Comment: @ArnoBozo You still have to add the argument, it’s just that in your answer you call it `client`, but I called it `self`. Perhaps the name you chose is clearer, but saying the `self` argument is not needed is not correct.

Comment: One argument was missing. It was not self/mosq/client, it was flags.

Comment: In python, the name of the positional arguments is not important, just the position. I will concede that I have not looked at the documentation for this API, but the root cause was that a variable was missing. You may argue that you inserted it into the third position instead of the first, but from python’s perspective it doesn’t care. If this were using keyword arguments it would be a whole different discussion, and what you are saying would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The signature requested for `on_connect` has changed after 0.9 version (latest is 1.4). You can see it here https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/v1.0/src/paho/mqtt/client.py

You can find many examples with the old signature on official documentation. However you must add the `flags` parameter:

```
on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc)
```

With the names you used, it would be declared:

```
def on_connect(mosq, obj, flags, rc)
```

With python2.7 my script worked with both signatures (I dont know how it managed to), but it did not with python3 (3.7).

Comment: For v1.6.1, this applies to `on_disconnect` too -- in `client._do_on_disconnect()`, when the MQTT version is 5, it is called with a fourth `properties` param.